# Webpack - How to set publicPath for images within scss file

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have some background images defined in scss file. I'm using ExtractTextPlugin with scss loader to extract css file in build directory. However, the issue is that the path which is outputted in compiled css file is incorrect. How can I modify the path which the css file contains through webpack bundler.

Webpack.config.js

```
/* Custom Config */
var ProgramID = '1111';

/* Default Config */
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var polyfill = require("babel-polyfill");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/Programs/' + ProgramID);
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/import');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
    APP_DIR + '/import.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR + '/',
    filename: '/js/bundle.js',
    publicPath: '../Programs/' + ProgramID
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react,plugins[]=transform-runtime'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css','sass'])
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=/images/[name].[ext]'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css"),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  process: function(path, filename) {
    if (filename.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) {
      path = babelJest.process(path, filename);
      path = webpackAlias.process(path, filename);
    }
    return path;
  },
  externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
};
```

Comment: you could use `url-loader`

Comment: I think that because you're using a root-relative path in your file-loader name it might fail. Remove the first `/` there.